# Smart case completion in Bash?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

In Vim, one can combine the following commands, `:set smartcase` + `:set ignorecase`, to make searching case-insensitive *unless* there is a capitalized letter in the search query, in which case it *is* case-sensitive.

In bash, one can make auto-completion case-insensitive by adding `set completion-ignore-case on` into their `~/.inputrc`.

Is there anyway to get the conditional case-sensitivity behavior similar to Vim's `smartcase` + `ignorecase` searching for bash auto-completion?

Comment: I think the first step is `exec zsh` and the second step is configuring this behavior on the new user setup interface (and the way it works is through [the `matcher-list` style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-matcher_002dlist_002c-completion-style)).

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit? Not sure I follow... Are you suggesting to use calls to `zsh` when pressing tab to get the zsh-supported smartcase completion?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting to ditch bash and use zsh instead. My first comment was wrong, I'd misread your request — what you can do through zsh's new user customization interface is to make completion case-sensitive, but fall back to case-insensitive if there's no match. This isn't what you wanted but may be good enough in practice. AFAIK what you want is doable in zsh (I think it can be done through zstyle) but can only be done on a command-by-command basis in bash.

Comment: Unfortunately, zsh is not a viable option for me at this time. I'm interested in a potential solution for bash, specifically.